# How to delete existing key from GlobalWindow in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was trying to delete the existing key from GlobalWIndow.

Not able to find any function to delete key.

```
DataStream<MyCollector> resStream = dataStream.keyBy(new MyKeySelector()).countWindow(Common.THREE, Common.ONE) .apply(new MyStream());
```

Suppose `MyKeySelector()` having person_id as key and Window having p1,p2,p3

and I want to execute fresh Window for p2. Basically, I want to delete  p2 key-related information.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Flink. Could You provide more details on what You want to achieve, so maybe there is a different way to do this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your example shows a CountWindow, not a GlobalWindow. Once a CountWindow is triggered it will clean up after itself.